# Swift & Parse - Empty PFFile

Tags: swift, mongodb, parse-platform, swift3, parse-server

I'm using Parse and MongoDB for my app, and I have a problem concerning PFFile.
I would like to save an empty PFFile on the server.
Indeed, the user doesn't have to send a picture but in an other way, it's possible.

I would like to set a default PFFile which is null.

```
    let imageFile: PFFile?

if previewImg.image != nil {
             // Send pic to server after converting to FILE and compression
             let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(previewImg.image!, 0.5)
             imageFile = PFFile(name: "step.jpg", data: imageData!)
          } else {
             imageFile = ""
          }

          object["stepImg"] = imageFile
```

This is my code. And my error is "cannot assign value of type string to type PFFile".

Do you have an idea about how I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a `PFFile?` so your variable can a PFFile or nil

This is the corrected code

```
let imageFile: PFFile?

if let previewImage = previewImg.image {
    // Send pic to server after converting to FILE and compression
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(previewImage, 0.5)
    object["stepImg"] = PFFile(name: "step.jpg", data: imageData!)
}
```

Comment: I also tried it but I have this error : "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Or if I write : object["stepImg"] = nil

"Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values."

Comment: Oh sorry I have change my answer

Comment: Same thing ... It's not possible because "" is not a PFFile. And I cannot save "" because mongoDB try to save a PFFile and not a string ....